# Single handle faucet problems

Tags: plumbing, faucet, water-pressure, valve

We have a single handle faucet in our kitchen sink, it started having issues where the water flow would sometimes be fine, sometimes non at all, or somewhere in between, at random, but almost never what would be considered functional. The model is [parts blowout](http://www.hajoca.com/Misc/reports/3lyxna54psnekr10tgqhb2g2/m92569991679.pdf#zoom=100); it has a cartridge style ceramic valve that one would assume works or does not, no in between.

So when the problem started I figured something in the valve was stuck, sure enough, when it would trickle, a sharp rap on top with a wooden spoon and it would open up and flow fully.

So lifetime warranty, contact manufacturer and they send me a new valve cartridge... This new one does it much less frequently, but it still does it.

Since the faucet is nothing more than a housing to route water through the valve to hoses and pipes... and just to make sure I was not losing my mind, I actually disconnected all hosing and verified there was no debris clogging one and moving around...  My only reasonable conclusions are -- new valve flawed same as old or something else is happening.

We have no other faucets of this type in the house, and this is the only faucet having an issue.

I have noticed what seems to be some hammer in the pipes lately that I never seem to have noticed before, is it possible this could be pressure related? We live on level ground with several new duplexes built up the hill up the road which leaves us between them and the pipe from water company, and we had to have a pressure regulator put on our home service a couple of years back because of this and some blown pipes... (maybe needs adjustment again?)

Figured a plumber may have seen something like this before and could comment before I hire one to come diagnose further.

Please and thank you.

Comment: Did you try taking off the sprayer head and open the faucet to see if water is coming out from the hose? maybe some debris in the head.

Comment: I had a single handle bathroom faucet with the same problem.  I replaced the cartridge, but eventually found the problem was lime in the aerator.

Comment: Sometimes there can be debris, grit, broken bits and pieces of old washers and old O-rings caught somewhere in the system. Check where debris usually collects; on the inside of the aerator screens. While the aerator is off check up inside the spout for any old aerator washers lost inside.

Comment: Yes in the OP I checked all of the hoses. Head/spray handle does not have a removable screen, but the trickle problem occurs from the hose as well, with the handle not attached. water flow from pipe=>hose=>valve is unobstructed, water flow valve=>hose=>head is unobstructed. Happens in hot and cold position. To test potential pressure problem I opened another faucet in house before operating this one, no change. Starting to believe bad second valve? But disassembly of valve is two functional parts, not really anything to go wrong... Hydraulic pressure only thing that seems to make sense.